# How to prove $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2<1\} \cup \{(x,y) \mid y=1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is path connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

How to prove $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2<1\} \cup \{(x,y) \mid y=1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is path connected ?

I could show above space is connected, but how to show path connectedness ?

Comment: How did you prove that it is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.**Hint:**

1. Write your space as $A\cup B$, where $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x^2+y^2<1\}\cup\{(0,1)\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|y=1\}$.
2. Prove that $A$ is path connected by showing that if $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in A$, then the line $\Vert t(x_1,y_1)+(1-t)(x_2,y_2)\Vert<1$ for all $t\in(0,1)$.
3. Prove that $B$ is path connected.
4. Prove that if two path connected spaces share a point, that their union is also path connected.
5. Prove that $A$ and $B$ have a point in common.